# Populate a textbox based on selectbox ajax php mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, php-5.3

I have a question. So I tried to populate the value of a textbox based on selectbox. My HTML:

```
<form id="form_gift" action="myAction" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Gift</label>
        <select id="statusSelect" name="{{ form_gift.gift.name }}" class="form-control" onChange="getPrix()">
            {% for key,category in form_gift.gift.choices %}
                <option value="{{ key }}">
                    {{ category }}
                </option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="">Price</label>
        <input type="text" id="{{ form_gift.prix.name }}" name="{{ form_gift.prix.name }}" value="" placeholder="" class="form-control" required="required"/>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    function getPrix() {
        var selectedId =   $("#statusSelect option:selected").val(),
            url_deploy = "http://"+window.location.hostname+"/getPrice";
        $.ajax({
            url: url_deploy,
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            data: { id:selectedId},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                $('#prix').val(result.Value);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

My PHP:

```
public function getPrix()
{
    if (isset($_POST['id']))
    {
        $iIdGift = $_POST['id'];
    }

    $o_Article = Article::find($iIdGift);
    $prix = $o_Article->articlePrice();
    error_log(print_r($prix,true), 3, "/var/tmp/error.log");
    return json_encode($prix);
}
```

I tested the PHP code and it works fine. The problem is when I tried to populate the selectbox, I think in the success method. Help me please! Thanks in advance!

Comment: An AJAX request can fail for hundreds of reasons. Have you debugged to check where the failure is at all? Is the request being sent? Are you getting data back from the server, or an error?

Comment: I tested : so data is sending with succes to php, and php send data to ajax also with success, the problem is when I tried to show the value in textbox

Comment: What's the format of the returned JSON?

Comment: Just a single value? That would appear to not be valid JSON.

Comment: I dont see the element with id `prix`.. where is it?

Comment: Is the id of the textbox field

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan now the format of json is like this:  
{"id":"59.90"}

Comment: do you want to append the result??  $('#prix').val($('#prix').val()+result.id);

Comment: @Gigel In that case you need to use `result.id`; try this:  `$('#prix').val(result.id);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="{{ form_gift.prix.name }}" name="{{ form_gift.prix.name }}" value="" placeholder="" class="form-control txtPrix" required="required"/>


   success: function (result) {
        $('.txtPrix').val(result.id);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the format of the returned JSON:

> the format of json is like this: {"id":"59.90"}

You need to access that value using the `id` key, try this:

```
success: function (result) {
    $('#prix').val(result.id);
}
```